# GWT Editor Framework: Drop Down List

Tags: gwt, editor, requestfactory

I'm looking for someone to point me in the right direction (link) or provide a code example for implementing a drop down list for a many-to-one relationship using `RequestFactory` and the `Editor` framework in `GWT`. One of the models for my project has a many to one relationship:

```
@Entity
public class Book {

  @ManyToOne
  private Author author;
}
```

When I build the view to add/edit a book, I want to show a drop down list that can be used to choose which author wrote the book. How can this be done with the `Editor` framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the drop-down list, you need a `ValueListBox<AuthorProxy>`, and it happens to be an editor of `AuthorProxy`, so all is well. But you then need to populate the list (`setAcceptableValues`), so you'll likely have to make a request to your server to load the list of authors.

Beware the `setAcceptableValues` automatically adds the current value (returned by `getValue`, and defaults to `null`) to the list (and `setValue` automatically adds the value to the list of acceptable values too if needed), so make sure you pass `null` as an acceptable value, or you call `setValue` with a value from the list *before* calling `setAcceptableValues`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Also, great documentation on your Posterous. That's been a solid resource. http://tbroyer.posterous.com/

Comment: The `ValueListBox` worked to allow me to populate a `<select>` element with Author values, but the driver does not set the right value. Setting a breakpoint on `setValue(T)` in `ValueListBox` shows the incoming value to be `null`. How can I get the correct value to be selected when I am editing a book that has an author already selected?

Comment: Are you sure you grabbed the author relation from the server? (i.e. included a `.with("author")` in your RequestFactory request; check with Firebug or similar whether the author comes back from the server or not) Usually, you'll use `.with(editorDriver.getPaths())` to make sure you request all required objects (`getPaths` computes required relationships from the editors/subeditors).

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but here's my two cents anyway.

I had some trouble with a similar scenario. The problem is that the acceptable values (`AuthorProxy` instances) were retrieved in a `RequestContext` different than the one the `BookEditor` used to edit a `BookProxy`.

The result is that the current `AuthorProxy` was always repeated in the `ValueListBox`when I tried to edit a `BookProxy` object. After some research I found [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/hQNJV2GQ_LM) in the GWT Google group, where Thomas explained that

> "EntityProxy#equals() actually compares their request-context and  stableId()."

So, as I could not change my editing workflow, I chose to change the way the `ValueListBox` handled its values by setting a custom `ProvidesKey` that used a different object field in its comparison process.

My final solution is similar to this:

```
@UiFactory
@Ignore
ValueListBox<AuthorProxy> createValueListBox ()
{
    return new ValueListBox<AuthorProxy>(new Renderer<AuthorProxy>()
    {
    ...
    }, new ProvidesKey<AuthorProxy>()
    {
        @Override
        public Object getKey (AuthorProxy author)
        {
            return (author != null && author.getId() != null) ? author.getId() : Long.MIN_VALUE;
        }
    });
}
```

This solution seems ok to me. I hope it helps someone else.