# How to remove null value from ValueListBox values

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I am new to GWT. I am writing a simple GWT program where I need to use a combo box for which I used an instance of `ValueListBox` . In that combo, I need to list out the numbers from 1 to 12 representing the months of a year. But the combo appends `null` value at the end. Can anyone please help me how to remove that `null` value ?

```
    final ValueListBox<Integer> monthCombo = new ValueListBox<Integer>(new Renderer<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public String render(Integer object) {
                return String.valueOf(object);
            }

            @Override
            public void render(Integer object, Appendable appendable) throws IOException {
                if (object != null) {

                    String value = render(object);
                    appendable.append(value);
                }
            }
        });
    monthCombo.setAcceptableValues(getMonthList());
    monthCombo.setValue(1);

    private List<Integer> getMonthList() {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }

        return list;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Call `setValue` before `setAcceptableValues`.

The reason is that the value is `null` when you call `setAcceptableValues`, and `ValueListBox` automatically adds any value (generally passed to `setValue`) to the list of acceptable values (so that the value is actually *set*, and can be selected by the user, and re-selected if she selected another value and wants to go back to the original one). Calling `setValue` first with a value that will be in the list of acceptable values negates this side-effect.

See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5477

Comment: I just quoted your answer on a previous similar question, lol :)

Comment: I tried this and it's not working. I still see null... it really feels like a bug, and not a feature. I'm running 2.5-rc1

Comment: @ThomasBroyer: what if we don't know what any acceptable values may be ahead of time? How should this be used if we would like just acceptable values, and no nulls or empty strings? UPDATE: I see `setAcceptableValues(Collections.emptyList());` is suggested for this, though this didn't work

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449356/gwt-editor-framework-drop-down-list):

> Beware the setAcceptableValues automatically adds the current value
>   (returned by getValue, and defaults to null) to the list (and setValue
>   automatically adds the value to the list of acceptable values too if
>   needed)

So try inversing the order in which you call setValue and setAcceptableValues as following:

```
monthCombo.setValue(1);
monthCombo.setAcceptableValues(getMonthList());
```