# How can I remove the empty value from a GWT ValueListBox?

Tags: java, gwt

Very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176626/how-to-remove-null-value-from-valuelistbox-values), I'd like to remove the empty value that appears while async loading a `ValueListBox`.  I won't know beforehand any value that may be rendered from my list of objects, so I cannot call `setValue(beforeHandVal)`.  Setting `setAcceptableValues(Collections.emptyList())` did not work.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: could you post your current code in which you create your listBox and fill it with data.

Comment: Instead of a empty value what you want to appear in the listbox?

Comment: Non-null, non empty string ("") values that are loaded async.